# Is it possible to restrict the update query in mongoDB to a specific limit?

Tags: php, sql, mongodb, updates

I want to update records in mongoDB collection to a fixed limit. Is there a way to do it in PHP/mongoDB?

I know well about `'multi'` flag. when `multi` is set `true` it will update all matching records else update only one record.

But what I need is that I want to update records in a collection to a fixed limit like in SQL.

ex. `UPDATE table SET x=10 wher x=1 LIMIT 10`

I am wondering whether it is possible with mongoDB?

Hope I am clear with my question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not at the moment, the best way is to, in query on the where to limit your records down by some kind of clause or to pick them out client side if it is only a few.

Comment: @Sammaye sry I didnt get you clearly. can you be bit more clear?

Comment: Basically you might be able to use another field with `x` in your query to limit the records to those you wanna update, this isn't normally true though. So the best way atm is to pull them out client side and operate there normally.

Answer (score 2):

It is not currently possible to restrict an update query, only a find query, to MongoDB from your application.

The best way of doing this currently is to pull those ten (or whatever) out on client side, within your PHP application, and work on them there updating them:

```
$cursor = $db->col->find(array('x' => 1))->limit(10)
foreach($cursor as $row){
    $row['x'] = 10;
    $db->col->save($row); // Update with set can be used too
}
```

Providing it is a small number you can also do as @nw90 said, which is to grab the `ObjectId`s out instead and then do that all in one query using an atomic `$set`.

You will want to watch out for this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1599

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function as far as I know. You could do a workaround: Just fetch the _id's of the documents you want to update and update all documents with those _id's